# Recursively inserting into a binary tree, passing pointer by value?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Here is my Node class.

```
class Node
{
private:
public:
  T data;
  Node<T>* left;
  Node<T>* right;
  Node(T dat) : data(dat), left(NULL), right(NULL)
  {}
};
```

Here is my insert function, defined in my Btree class:

```
public:
  Node<T>* root;
  Btree() : root(NULL){}
  void insert(T data, Node<T>* parent)
  {   
      if( !parent  )
      {   
        parent = new Node<T>(data);
        return;
      }   
      else if(data < parent->data)
      {   
        insert(data, parent->left);
      }   
      else if(data > parent->data)
      {   
        insert(data, parent->right);
      }   
  }

};
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
  Btree<int> tree;

  tree.insert(5, tree.root);

  cout << tree.root->data << endl;

  tree.insert(6, tree.root);

  cout << tree.root->right->data << endl;

}
```

When I run, I get a seg fault.

I think it is because the pointer variable parent is passed by value, so when I create a new Node that is pointed to by parent, once I exit the insert function I lose it?  Does that mean I have to use a double pointer here?

Can someone give me a thorough explanation about what's going on in memory that is making this not work out as planned.  Is my diagnosis correct here or is there something else wrong?

When I pass tree.root as the second parameter to insert, I am passing a Node*, I know that much.  Now, even if it is passed by value, will it not be the same address that I passed from the invoking main function.  So when I say parent (which is the address which I passed from main, tree.root) = new Node, should that not create a new Node on the heap that at the address of parent, aka the address of tree.root?  Why does passing by value fudge this up?

Comment: Rather than guessing, you can run your program in a debugger, which will tell you **exactly** which line caused the seg-fault.  You can then inspect variable values, etc. to figure out what happened.

Comment: I know which line caused the seg fault, I am asking for a clarification of passing addresses by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with passing by value in this case is that all assignments made to the formal argument inside the function are not visible to the caller. Therefore, this assignment

```
if( !parent  )
{   
    parent = new Node<T>(data); // <<== HERE
    return;
}
```

has no effect on the `tree.root` in the caller:

```
tree.insert(5, tree.root);
```

The value of the `parent` pointer in the function is changed, and then promptly discarded; tree's `root` remains `NULL`.

A fix to this problem would be passing a pointer to a pointer, like this:

```
void insert(T data, Node<T>** parent) {
    if( !*parent  )
    {
        *parent = new Node<T>(data);
        return;
    }
    else if(data < (*parent)->data)
    {
        insert(data, &((*parent)->left));
    }
    else if(data > (*parent)->data)
    {
        insert(data, &((*parent)->right));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ passes by value, so that `parent` is a copy of the passed-in pointer. Assigning to it therefore has no lasting effect. The easiest way to fix this is to change the signature of the method so that it accepts a reference to the pointer. This will automatically make the compiler update the original pointer while avoiding having to the change the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

**dasblinkenlight** answered it best. But, there is a more succinct solution:

Get the reference of the pointer (known as reference to pointer):

```
void insert(T data, Node<T>*& parent)
  {   
      if( !parent  )
      {   
        parent = new Node<T>(data);
        return;
      }   
      else if(data < parent->data)
      {   
        insert(data, parent->left);
      }   
      else if(data > parent->data)
      {   
        insert(data, parent->right);
      }   
  }
```

See more here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer